# Retrieve data from Firestore to ListView not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've spend two days in this code but I can't print one data from the field "title" in my listView. The app just crashes. It prints items normally but not items from `Firestore`. It grabs the data, but it just don't appear in the ListView. It says `" Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Iterator com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.iterator()' on a null object reference"`

Pretty sure it has something to do with the for loop, I just can't figure out what.

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        final ListView lista = findViewById(R.id.listviewzika);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new EscolaAdapter(this, adicionarEscolas());
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private ArrayList<Escola> adicionarEscolas() {
        final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        final ArrayList<Escola> escolas = new ArrayList<Escola>();

        db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot: value){

                    Escola e = new Escola("femur", "nod");
                    escolas.add(e);
                   
                }

            }
        });

        Escola e = new Escola("mya", "Tempo: 3 horas e 21 minutos");
        escolas.add(e);

        return escolas;
     }

}
```

and this is the getter and setter

```
public class Escola {

    private String nome;
    private String endereco;

    public Escola(String nome, String endereco) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.endereco = endereco;
      
    }
  
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

  
    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `QuerySnapshot` is `null` if there was an error. So when you checked the `FirebaseFirestoreException` the issue should have been clear?

Comment: My friend, it should be clear to you that people here are not experts in programming. I'm a beginner. Right. I hope that this information enters your brain. But thanks for this tip.

Comment: I was trying to help by hinting that you'd written something that was generated for you and you didn't research it, which in my experience is always a likely source of bugs/solutions to them. But sorry I didn't get that across, I'll make sure to avoid commenting/answering your questions in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you return a list from `adicionarEscolas()` before the firebase can take a chance to return its data; firebase callbacks run in background threads so they take time until they can return data to your app, and that is the reason that your list returns data that filled in locally in the app.

So, you can't return the `ArrayList<Escola>` from `adicionarEscolas()`, because you don't know when the this data is ready to be returned.

## Solution:

**Option 1:** use a listener with a callback that accepts `ArrayList<Escola>` parameter, and whenever this callback is triggered, then fill in the data and notify the changes to the list.

**Option 2:** fill-in the data within the `onEvent()` callback to make sure that the data came down to the app.

And here is Option 2 implementation:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<Escola> escolas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

    private void adicionarEscolas() {
        final FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        escolas = new ArrayList<Escola>();

        db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot: value){
                    Escola e = new Escola("femur", "nod");
                    escolas.add(e); 
                }
                
                final ListView lista = findViewById(R.id.listviewzika);
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new EscolaAdapter(this, escolas);
                lista.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }
}
```